# Exists api has no effect on nested field?

Tags: elasticsearch

`Exists` api has no effect on `netsed` field ?

`dsl` json:

```
 {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "LableToMember"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

One doc:

```
{
    "LableToMember": [
        {
            "xxx": "xxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

`LableToMember` is a nested field and i can't get any doc.Other type works ok except `nested` field.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) for nested fields.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "LableToMember",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "LableToMember"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```